# 'printf' después de un 'return' no muestra nada

Tags: c

estoy aprendiendo C y en el siguiente código da un resultado que no entiendo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int patata();

int main()
{
  printf("me gustan los frijoles\n");
  return 0;
}

int patata()
{
  printf("las patatas me gustan más\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Resultado:

```
Me gustan los frijoles
```

Muchas gracias de ante mano por la ayuda.

Comment: Quieres que el `return` te devuelva ese mensaje?, no me quedó del todo claro tu problema

Comment: No, lo que no entiendo del código es que el segundo 'printf' no se muestre en pantalla.

Comment: Llama la función `patata()` dentro del `main()`, ya que el main es el primero en ejecutarse y ejecutar lo que lleva dentro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El punto de entrada del programa es `main()`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int patata(); // Declaras la función pero no se ejecuta

int main() // <- Punto de entrada
{
  printf("me gustan los frijoles\n"); // <- Se ejecuta
  return 0; // <- Finaliza el programa.
}

int patata() // Se vuelve a declarar, pero esta vez definiendola
{
  printf("las patatas me gustan más\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Para que se ejecute la funcion `patata` tienes que llamarla desde el `main`

```
int main()
{
   printf("me gustan los frijoles\n");
   patata();
   return 0;
}
// me gustan los frijoles
// las patatas me gustan más
```

Comment: Vale, pero en el siguiente código, no funciona el llamarla desde 'main': #include <stdio.h> int main (); void patata(int); int main () { int manzana; printf("Me gustan las lentejas\n"); return 0; } void patata(int manzana) { printf("Me gustan mas las patatas\n"); } Resultado: Me gustan las lentejas

Comment: En ese código no la estas llamando. Solo estas definiendo una variable que por casualidad se llama igual la variable que `patata` acepta, pero que `manzana` exista dentro de `main` no hace nada... Tienes que llamar explicitamente a `patata()` como te lo mostré en la repuesta

Comment: Vale, gracias. 'patata(manzana);'.

Comment: Si te ha sido de utilidad, puedes marcar esta respuesta como correcta